# How do I evaluate if a string is a number or boolean in Haxe?

Tags: types, casting, type-conversion, haxe

Using `Std.isOfType()` returns `false` when I'm evaluating an int and bool like this:

```
Std.isOfType('123', Int); // returns false instead of true
Std.isOfType('true', Bool); // returns false instead of true
```

So what is the proper way to do it? I am always going to receive a String so I want to determine it's type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided code is returning false because you are passing a String data type, instead of the data types you are testing for.

To correct this, you just have to pass the data directly to the isOfType method, shown below:

```
Std.isOfType(123, Int); // returns true
Std.isOfType(true, Bool); // returns true
```

If you wanted to pass in a string (as you are currently), then you will just have to parse the string into the appropriate data type before testing, such as:

```
Std.isOfType(Std.parseInt('123'), Int)
```

From quickly reading the documentation, I don't see a way to parse a string boolean into an actual boolean.

Comment: I was trying to identify what kind of variable a string value is because it will always come in as a string from the end user

Comment: @user9564371 As noted in the second part of my answer, there is a built-in function for converting a string to an int, however, there isn't one for converting a string to a boolean. 

What you could do in this case is to write your own function that tests it, and converts it to a boolean data type. I created a quick [example here](https://try.haxe.org/#6f831D3E). The function isn't perfect, however, it might work for you.